# Do I really need to use Intent to call activity?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Do I really need to use `Intent` to call activity form as shown below? As you can see I also pass some objects like `Dog` and receive it third activity inside `OnCreate` method. My question is couldn't it be just like I could create constructor in my third activity and pass some arguments there instead of using `Intent` and `bundle` to pass values or it's just like it has to be done this way?

**I call Third activity from other activity:**

```
private void OpenOtherActivityWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
      Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(ThirdActivity));
      Dog mydog = new Dog("mydogName");
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.PutSerializable("mydoggy", mydog);
      nextActivity.PutExtra("RowID", Convert.ToString(10));
      nextActivity.PutExtras(bundle);
      StartActivity(nextActivity);
}
```

**ThirdActivity:**

```
 [Activity(Label = "ThirdActivity")]
 public class ThirdActivity : Activity
 {
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.third);

            //Receive values if any from previous activity
            if (!Intent.HasExtra("mydoggy")) return;
            Dog tryme = (Dog)Intent.GetSerializableExtra("mydoggy");
            if (!Intent.HasExtra("RowID")) return;
            string text = Intent.GetStringExtra("RowID") ?? "0";
        }
}
```

Comment: yes, that's how Android works, you cannot use contructor to pass values as Android OS need paramterles constructor to recreate Activity

Comment: you may create static method which would return intent for you from given parameters, also you should use rather constant for extras's keys(fx private const in ThirdActivity and add `public static Intent CreateIntent(Dog dog, int rowID)` and use those constants in OnCreate and this method and in ThirdActivity`OpenOtherActivityWindow_Click` use it like `StartActivity(ThirdActivity.CreateIntent(new Dog(), 10)`)

Comment: @Selvin can you also show me possiblecontent inside CreateIntent? I cannot use "return this" including Dog and rowId. Lets alsoassume Dog and rowId are properties of ThirdActivity.

Comment: @Selvin can you please answer, thanks

Comment: Usually we use intent to open another activiy and pass the data with it,if you don want to use intent to pass data,you could use the `Application` global object to pass it or save the data local first then get it when you open another activity with [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android)

Answer (score -2):

According to Selvin those constructors have to stay parameterless. I have no contrary information. But that does not mean you can not make it easier for you to use/create those instances.

**Option 1 - Factory Method:**

Usually you use Factory Methods for cases where the constructors are Private. The idea is that some work has to be done at runtime, you do not want to confront the average user of your class with. Or you are using the singleton pattern.

A function that calls a public constructor to then set some public fields would be odd, but a possibility

**Option 2 - Initializers:**

[Object Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) are a thing in C#. Now it is rather important to understand that Initializers are **not** the same as a Parametized Constructor. It is just syntax sugar. With a Initializer you call the Parameterless constructor and the values are then assigned to the public variables/fields the same as if you had written it over several lines.

**Option 3 - Inverse the chaining:**

Normally when you chain constructors, you chain from the one with the *least* parameters to one with the *most*. With every step adding a new default value. The nromal direction is away from the Parameterless Constructor. Just keep in mind that once you add any Constructor, the Implicit Parameterless constructor will cease to be - you have to make it a explicit one.

Asuming it is not a sealed class you are dealing with or the specific case limits it to a single constructor, you could subclass it and add a lot of parametized constructors. Wich would all just call the parameterelss base constructor via chaining, then assign values.

If you do got one of the Problematic cases: especially for those cases, extension methods have been invented.

Comment: non of this method will work for Android ... about 1: **Activity can be only created by system with `Context.StartActivity` system will only call paramterless constructor**  about 2: see point 1 ... you cannot call `new ActivityDerivedClass { Prop = 1, Prop2 = 2}` (acctually you can ... but you cannot use it as real Activity then) about point 3: again see point 1

Comment: the only use for constructor with parameters are abstract classes which would be derived ... but then you still can only pass parameters there from parmaterless constructor ... in android platform there a few classes which cannot be created by you they are called application componets like Application, Acivity, Service, ContentProvider and BroadcastReceiver(this can be created by you)

Comment: While you answer is good for normal C# classes it is not apply to classes derived from  android's Activity class

Comment: @Selvin So `Context.StartActivity` is a factory Method. You are telling me one Factory Method can not call another? All Factory methods **do** is deal with the Idiosincracies of instance creation. Normally it is calling a private constructor and providing values at runtime, that the user should not have to deal with. But this case should work too. Example 1: Creates a `Intent`, `Dog` and `Bundle` Instance. Puts the Dog in the Bundle. Adds some UI value and then the Bundle to the Intent. The sends the Intent Instanfce off to `this.StartActivity()`.

Comment: oh so you wrote about `Intent` class not `Activity`? then please add this informationin the answer